# Infinitesimals in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

Is it possible to parse for Mathematica the following function ?

```
f[x_] := x + t,
```

Where `t` is infinitesimal $dx$ ?

I work on time scale calculus, and defined a forward jump operator $\sigma(x)$, which is different for different time-scales. For example, for $\mathbb{T} =\mathbb{Z}$ the sigma is $\sigma(x) = x+1$. However, for time scale $\mathbb{T} =\mathbb{R}$ the sigma is $\sigma(x) = x+dx$. This gives an approach to receive different dertivatves like $q-$derivative, finite difference, etc. just changing the sigma function $\sigma(x)$. And the problem is time scale $\mathbb{T} =\mathbb{R}$, since, in order to hold it, it is necessary to modify $\sigma(x)$ and add another parameter, and then overload derivative function for new sigma. So I'm looking for an approach to get $\sigma(x) = x + dx$ in terms of Mathematica.

Comment: If it were possible, what would you like to do with it? Perhaps if you provide more context to your problem, we might be able to help you with a more general solution.

Comment: I've modified question, so there is a concrete problem, thank you

Comment: To expand on the question from @MarcoB, you already have a sum `x+t`. What operations do you want to support such that `t` behaves as the differential `dx`?

Comment: In order to hold the case os time scale T = R it is necessary to use limit form of derivative, e.g it is necessary to rewrite sigma as $\sigma(x, t) = x + t$ and therefore use limit to reach derivative, otherwise it is 1/0 exception. I just need this value to be $\sigma(x) = x + 1/ \infty$

Comment: I would think that you have answered your own question. Just define `sigma[x,t]:=x+t` and use `Limit` on `f[sigma[x,dx]]`, with `dx->0`.

Comment: Does anyone know: What ever came from [this article](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11424857_56) and the `timescale` package?